# Batch rename image files by age plus add date and variable to filename

Tags: bash, rename, date, gawk

*The question is completely rewritten due to things learned from the first two answers and comments that I was unaware of when first asking.*

---

After a photo shoot I come home with files that look like `_DSC1234.NEF`. `NEF` is Nikon's camera raw file format, so `EXIF` data is present in the files.

I would like to automatically rename them with three parts:

1. Creation date in the format `YYYYMMDD`
2. Name of Shoot
3. Number of Image

So the final file name should look like this

`20140707_NameOfShoot_0001.NEF`

There are a few issues:

**ad 1. Creation date**
sometimes I can only copy and rename the files a few days after shooting, so the date should reflect the date the picture was taken, not the date it was copied. `mtime` seems like the best bet here or if possible creation date from `EXIF`.

**ad 2: Name of Shoot**
This would ideally be a variable I could set as a parameter on calling the script.

**ad  3. Number of Image**
This should reflect the age of the image, the oldest having the lowest number. The problem is that cameras usually restart numbering at `0000` after they hit `9999`. So `9995-9999` can potentially be older than `0000-0004`. I am looking for a solution that reflects file age and in this special case would rename

- _DSC0000.NEF -> 20140707_FOO_0004.NEF
- _DSC0001.NEF -> 20140707_FOO_0005.NEF
- _DSC0002.NEF -> 20140707_FOO_0006.NEF
- ...
- _DSC9997.NEF -> 20140707_FOO_0001.NEF
- _DSC9998.NEF -> 20140707_FOO_0002.NEF
- _DSC9999.NEF -> 20140707_FOO_0003.NEF

Again, either `mtime` or if possible creation date from `EXIF` seem right.

---

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers) I have a working solution which renames all .NEF-files in a folder by date:

```
find -name '*.NEF' | 
gawk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ printf "mv %s %04d.NEF\n", $0, a++ }' | 
bash
```

Hard coding file-modification-date and the shootname works well, but it would be great if it could be automated.

For the timestamp I find articles on `strftime()`, `mktime()`, `systime()` but I don't understand how to use them to return file modification date. I also tried to add `DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")` and add `$DATE` to the gawk-line, which leads to deletion of all files in current folder (and probably is systime anyway and not change time).

For the variable, I tried

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ printf "mv %s $1_%04d.NEF\n", $0, a++ }' |
```

and call the script with `./rename FOO`, but FOO is ignored in renaming.

Comment: I also tried using digikam for batch rename, which works fine but took roughly 1sec/file on my last 1600+ photos, which I find is a bit slow

Comment: I tried `stat -c %W -- *` in my home directory just now and returned only a bunch of zeroes. Also GNU's `man find` page documents that it can handle `-printf` `strftime` sequences for `%A`ccess, status `%C`hange and modification `%T`imes but nothing about file creation or birth. While that doesn't come close to decisively proving it can't be done, I think it's a good indicator that it's not a commonly available function.

Comment: hm. what's the difference in between change and modification? That would probably do anyway. If birth is unavailable, can you see what the solution above uses for sorting? Cause I don't really understand what it is doing.

Comment: that's status change. Have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2465/52934) - I think it's a pretty good indicator too. Maybe there are file systems that report on creation time - I'm not sure - but I don't think many do.

Comment: grand, thanks a lot. and yes, that should do. any idea on how I can put that into my filename?

Comment: status change? Do you have GNU `find`? - cause it can do pretty much all of it.

Comment: No, I'll look into that, thanks. And you mean, it would also replace the code I already have? Or would I have to combine it with gawk?

Comment: what about `stat`? Either one should do if sorted. But, yeah, if you have those I can answer the question without `gawk`. I assume you have them because `gawk` should be GNU too.

Comment: I absolutely don't insist on gawk, it's just the closest I found when looking for a solution.

Comment: Ok - but do you have them? GNU `stat` and/or GNU `find`? They'd make it easy.

Comment: I have `findutils` and `coreutils` – is that it? I am on crunchbang by the way.

Comment: yeah. That will do it. I've just posted the answer - be sure to test it, though, please, to make sure it does do what you want.

Comment: Beware that the change time is almost certainly not what you want — it's always more recent than the modification time, it's typically the last time you copied the file, or changed its permissions, etc. The modification time is often the closest thing you can get to the creation time (and is always closer than the change time).

Comment: @Seul - in truth I'm inclined to agree with Gilles. I didn't bother to argue it after providing you a link on the subject providing more and better info than any offered here. Still, if you find that he's correct, please let me know as well. `stat` can do the same with mod time as it does with change time - but I will have to change the `%z` in my answer to a `%y`.

Comment: @mikeserv yes, I think mod-time comes closest to what I need – I probably misunderstood the explanation behind your link and have edited my original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most unices don't track a file's creation date¹. “Creation date” is ill-defined anyway (does copying a file create a new file?). You can use the file's modification time, which is by a reasonable interpretation the date at which the latest version of the data was created. If you make copies of the file, make sure to retain the modification time (e.g. `cp -p` or `cp -a` if you use the `cp` command, not bare `cp`).

A few file formats have a field inside the file where the creator application fills in a creation date. This is often the case for photos, where the camera will fill in some [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data in JPEG or TIFF images, including the creation time. Nikon's NEF image format wraps around TIFF and supports Exif as well.

There are ready-made tools to rename image files containing Exif data to include the creation date in the file name. [renaming images to include creation date in name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110579/renaming-images-to-include-creation-date-in-name) shows two solutions, with [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/).

I don't think either tool lets you include a counter in the file name. You can do your renaming in two passes: first include the date (with as high resolution as possible to retain the order) in the file name, then number the files according to that date part (and chuck away the time). Since modern DSLRs can fire bursts of images (Nikon's D4s shoots at 11fps) it is advisable to retain the original filename as well in the first phase, as otherwise it would potentially lead to several files with the same file name.

```
exiv2 mv -r %Y%m%d-%H%M%S:basename: *.NEF
# exiv2 uses `strftime(3)`, so `%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` returns YYYYMMDD-hhmmss
# :basename: is a naming variable exiv2's `-r`-handle provides. See `exiv2 -h` for more  
# Now you have files with names like 20140630-235958_DSCC1234.NEF.
# Note that chronological order and lexicographic order agree with this naming format.
i=10000
for x in *.NEF; do
  i=$((i+1))
  mv "$x" "${x%-*}_FOO_${i#1}.NEF"
done
```

`${x%-*}` removes the part after the `-` character. The counter variable `i` counts from 10000 and is used with the leading `1` digit stripped; this is a trick to get the leading zeroes so that all counter values have the same number.

[Rename files by incrementing a number within the filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40523/rename-files-by-incrementing-a-number-within-the-filename) has other solutions for renaming a bunch of files to include a counter.

If you want to use a file's timestamp rather than Exif data, see [Renaming a bunch of files with date modified timestamp at the end of the filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43338/renaming-a-bunch-of-files-with-date-modified-timestamp-at-the-end-of-the-filenam)

---

As a general note, don't generate shell code and then pipe it into a shell. It's needlessly convoluted. For example, instead of

```
find -name '*.NEF' | 
gawk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ printf "mv %s %04d.NEF\n", $0, a++ }' | 
bash
```

you can write

```
find -name '*.NEF' | 
gawk 'BEGIN{ a=1 }{ system(sprintf("mv %s %04d.NEF\n", $0, a++)) }'
```

Note that both versions could lead to catastrophic results if a file name contained shell special characters (such as spaces, `'`, `$`, `` ` ``, etc.) since the file name is interpreted as shell code. There are ways to turn this into robust code, but this isn't the easiest approach, so I won't pursue that approach.

---

¹  <sub>Note that there is something called the “ctime”, but the `c` isn't for *creation*, it's for *change*. The ctime changes every time anything changes about the file, either in its content or in its metadata (name, permissions, …). The ctime is pretty much the antithesis of a creation time.</sub>

Comment: You make a very general point and then base it on very specific examples - this is very close to a *baseless* argument. *Don't generate shell code then pipe it to a shell* is the statement to which I refer. There is another answer here which already does this robustly, but the method for which you have seemingly ignored altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It works pretty well but has two small issues and a larger one.

Comment: @Seul What do original file names look like? I thought that `NameOfShoot` was from the original file name. Regarding the dates, I'm not familiar with the NEF format — does it include a creation stamp inside the file format? For example JPEG images can include the date at which the picture was taken (it's part of the EXIF data), many (but not all) cameras do that. Regarding the sorting, do you want the oldest file to be 0001, the next-oldest to be 0002, etc.?

Comment: yes, NEF is Nikon's camera Raw format, so all exif si present. the original format is `_DSC1234.NEF`, will add that to original question, too.

Comment: and yes, oldest should get the lowest number. –– on a sidenote: I get asked by stackexchange if I would rather chat than add all this to comments. I am not too familiar with etiquette here, please let me know if I can improve my style.

Comment: @Seul I've significantly rewritten my answer, now that I assume that these files contain Exif data, the right solution is to extract that Exif data and there are ready-made tools to rename files based on the creation time recorded in Exif.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a million! And sorry I was not specific enough in my original question – learned a lot along the way, though.

Comment: @Gilles - this is really good. I appreciate the rewrite as well.

Comment: @Gilles: I edited your answer to cater for the problematic case when bursts of images have the same time stamp. Now it should be a very robust solution that only breaks if a burst of images with the same time stamp is shot over the `9999`-`0000` reset, I have no idea how to solve this but I think it is such a rare case that it wight not be important.

Comment: @Gilles: one thing I noticed while testing is that I had to change the character that triggers the deletion of the following string in the second part of your script. My original file names already have a `_` in place, so the script used the wrong one. I have no better idea than using `-` but maybe there is a solution that is more generic.

Answer (score 4):

```
stat --printf='}" "%z_${SN}_${LINENO}"\n' -- * | 
nl -nln -w1 -s '' |
sort -k2,3 | 
sed 's| ..:[^_]*||;s|-||g;s|^|echo mv "${|' |
SN=SHOOTNAME sh -s -- *
```

The above command should do what you need. It is perhaps more general-purposed than you have requested - but please see the bottom of this answer for a more specific example.

It works by `*`globbing all the files in the current directory and printing out their change times. For just files in the current directory containing the suffix `.NEF` you'll want to change the `*`globstar at the ends of both lines 1 and 5 to `*.NEF`. It appends some shell variables and quotes to the end - the names for which only exist at the other end of the pipeline in the `sh` subshell.

Also, because we specify the filenames just by their glob order - or the `${1}` shell type parameters this works fine with any filename - whatever weird characters it may contain.

For now the command includes an `echo` - it's nerfed. Running is essentially a no-op - it just shows you what it wants to do. Here's its output from my home directory before feeding it to `sh`:

```
echo mv "${2}" "20140611_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${4}" "20140614_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${11}" "20140617_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${7}" "20140622_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${8}" "20140622_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${1}" "20140624_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${10}" "20140704_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${5}" "20140704_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${9}" "20140704_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${12}" "20140705_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${3}" "20140705_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${13}" "20140706_${SN}_${LINENO}"
echo mv "${6}" "20140706_${SN}_${LINENO}"
```

Here it is after `sh`:

```
mv Desktop-1 20140611_SHOOTNAME_1
mv Library 20140614_SHOOTNAME_2
mv target.txt 20140617_SHOOTNAME_3
mv script.sh 20140622_SHOOTNAME_4
mv script.sh~ 20140622_SHOOTNAME_5
mv Desktop 20140624_SHOOTNAME_6
mv shot-2014-06-22_17-11-06.jpg 20140704_SHOOTNAME_7
mv Terminology.log 20140704_SHOOTNAME_8
mv shot-2014-06-22_17-10-16.jpg 20140704_SHOOTNAME_9
mv test 20140705_SHOOTNAME_10
mv Downloads 20140705_SHOOTNAME_11
mv test.tar 20140706_SHOOTNAME_12
mv new
file 20140706_SHOOTNAME_13
```

You might notice that my output shows a few image files already named for their creation time but their new assigned name does not match. This is not an effect of the `sort` - which works as prescribed - but rather that those files last had a status change on that date. Nevertheless, as you've specified in the comments on this question `ctime` is the property you're looking for, that is the sort and name property offered here. Still, here is `stat`'s output with filenames attached:

```
stat -c '%z %n' -- *

2014-06-24 16:50:09.110283839 -0700 Desktop
2014-06-11 23:34:02.981981145 -0700 Desktop-1
2014-07-05 01:00:43.213344635 -0700 Downloads
2014-06-14 10:32:13.537014418 -0700 Library
2014-07-04 23:02:25.079690701 -0700 Terminology.log
2014-07-06 11:24:05.398936386 -0700 new
file
2014-06-22 11:26:53.658004123 -0700 script.sh
2014-06-22 11:26:53.658004123 -0700 script.sh~
2014-07-04 13:34:00.063296353 -0700 shot-2014-06-22_17-10-16.jpg
2014-07-04 13:34:00.066629687 -0700 shot-2014-06-22_17-11-06.jpg
2014-06-17 19:59:38.475358571 -0700 target.txt
2014-07-05 23:53:39.097065292 -0700 test
2014-07-06 00:38:57.060521397 -0700 test.tar
```

The above output should also help me demonstrate what the whole pipeline is doing.

- So `stat --printf='}" "%z_${SN}_${LINENO}"\n'` prints out lines that look like:

  `}" "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.NS -TZ_${SN}_${LINENO}"`

... where `YMDHMS.NS -TZ` are the various `strftime` components they represent for `ctime`. Its output format is identical for `%w` - time of file birth - `%x` - time of last access - or `%y` - time of last modification, and so substituting any one of these for `%z` in the statement above will expand instead to their values. As we've already discussed in the comments though, `%w` - file birth time - is not a reliable attribute, and where it is unsupported it expands only to `0`.

It does this for every file the shell globs for it in `*` or whatever shell glob you provide it - such as `*.NEF` for only files in the current directory with the `.NEF` suffix.

- That list is handed to `nl` which numbers each line incremented by 1. Its line `-n`umbers are `ln` left-justified and not zero-padded with a minimum `-w`idth of 1 and only a `''` null-string to `-s`eparate them from the contents of the line. It outputs:

  `I}" "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.NS -TZ_${SN}_${LINENO}"`

... where `I` is the number of each line.

- `sort` sorts its input from the `-k2,3` second field through the third - or on `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.NS`. Since at this point the only unique quality of any line is either `I` or the date and `I` is skipped, there is no need to be any more specific than that. This also addresses the comment you made regarding files named by number and not by date. I *should* have done the `sort` before `sed` in the first place but it didn't occur to me to sort on minutes and seconds and the like.

My test base for this was generated like:

```
for s in 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1; do touch $s && sleep 1; done
```

If I `sort` *after* `sed` - as I did before this edit - then this would rename files so that `9` became `${DATE}.SHOOTNAME.9` because each file's `YMD` fields are identical and `sort` would not affect their line order. But with this adjustment this command is `sort` specific to the nanosecond and so `9` is renamed to `${DATE}.SHOOTNAME.1` and vice versa for `1`. Thanks, @Seul, for bringing that to my attention.

- `sed` then removes the first string that looks like `<space><any char><any char>:<colon>` and all characters that follow in sequence that are `^`not an `_`underscore. So at this point the line looks like:

  `I}" "YYYY-MM-DD_${SN}_${LINENO}"`

...next it removes all `-`dashes. And finally it inserts `echo mv "${` at the `^`head of each line, so it looks like this:

```
echo mv "${I}" "YYYYMMDD_${SN}_${LINENO}"
```

- Last a `sh`ell is invoked with the environment variable `$SN` declared - here its value is `SHOOTNAME`. POSIX specifies that the shell increment the var `$LINENO` for every line it reads in, so for each line we feed it that value in the filename should expand to one more than the last. If - as your comments indicate - for some reason this does not occur, a perfectly valid substitute is `$((i=i+1))` as first printed by `stat` in line 1 of the pipeline and as I've provided in a specific example below.

The shell is also invoked with its positional parameters set to our glob - here the `*`globstar for all files in the current directory. As already mentioned, `*.NEF` in this line and in the first would serve to only operate on files in the current directory with the filename suffix of `.NEF`.

So long as its glob is the same as that in the first line, it will glob them in the same order as `nl` numbered them. So no matter the line on which it occurs `"${1}"` will expand to the same filename we've assigned it according to `nl`'s output. This way you can rename the files in date order quickly and safely and in the correct order.

- As also already mentioned, I have nerfed the command with `echo` here. But if you run the `echo` and find it suits you after all you'll need to remove the `echo`.

Like this:

```
stat --printf='}" "%z_${SN}_${LINENO}"\n' -- * | 
nl -nln -w1 -s '' |
sort -k2,3 |
sed 's| ..:[^_]*||;s|-||g;s|^|mv "${|' |
SN=SHOOTNAME sh -s -- *
```

Or maybe:

```
export SN=SHOOTNAME SUFX=.NEF
stat --printf='}" "%z_${SN}_$((i=i+1))${SUFX}"\n' -- *$SUFX | 
nl -nln -w1 -s '' |
sort -k2,3 |
sed 's| ..:[^_]*||;s|-||g;s|^|mv "${|' |
sh -s -- *$SUFX
```

And here it is worked into a shell function:

```
_batch_date_rename () ( # a big one
    ERR= # for error reporting
    export "DIR=$1" "SUFX=$2" \ # args 1,2 must be dirname and file suffix
        "NAME=${3-${ERR:?no rename string specified}}" \ # need name string
        "TIME=${4-%y}" INT=$((${INT:-25}*3)) ${NOCONFIRM+NOCONFIRM=}
        #all above vars are exported to all points below
    _path_chk () { #run once at start - fn quits if any below test fails
        [ -d "$1" ] && [ -w "$1" ] && set -- "$1"/*"$2" && [ -e "$1" ]
    } # chks for user writable dirname and resolvable $1/*$2 glob
    _print_fmt () { #shell printf now not stat - last field zero padded
        printf 'mv "${%d}" "${DIR}/%d_${NAME}_%04d${SUFX}"\n' "$@"
    }
    _print_mv () { #prints copy of mv action before attempting 
        echo '(set -x' #uses shells debug printer to show expanded vals
        printf ': ${0+%s}\n' "$@" \
            ${NOCONFIRM-'Key "ENTER" to accept or "CTRL+C" to quit'}
        echo \) #above can be disabled by declaring NOCONFIRM at invocation
    } #by default fn batches 25 mvs at a time, displays them, and confirms
    _read_loop () { #parses piped in with IFS, batches in INTerval of 25
        argc=${1-$argc} ; ${1+shift} #total globbed files - quit point
        while IFS=' -' read nl y m d na ; do #split on -
            set -- "$@" "$nl" "$y$m$d" "$((i=i+1))" #build array until
            [ "$#" -ge "$INT" ] && break #hit interval
        done ; IFS='
';      set -- $(_print_fmt "$@") && unset IFS #finalize array in _print_fmt
        _print_mv "$@" #do the debug out
        ${NOCONFIRM+:} read < /dev/tty #if $NOCONFIRM not set confirm
        printf '%s\n' "$@" #now print the actual command
        [ $((argc>i)) -eq 1 ] || echo 'exit 0' #check if quit point     
        _read_loop #if not quit repeat
    }                                                                    
    _pipeline () { #this is mostly same - no sed though
        stat -c "$TIME" -- "$@" | nl -nln -w1 -s ' ' | sort -k2,3 | {
            _read_loop $# || echo 'exit 1' #read loop stands in for sed
        } | sh -s -- "$@" #sh still evaluates on args
    } #only two calls from main function below
    _path_chk "$1" "$2" || ${ERR:?Invalid pathname parameters specified}
    _pipeline "$DIR"/*"$SUFX" #if _path_chk do _pipeline
) #that's all folks
```

That uses the shell to some things I was doing with other utilities. The concept is the same - glob a file list, sort in different ways and store the sort order. What's *really* different about this thought is that it batches move operations by interval, displays to the user what it is about to to do and awaits a prompt before continuing. I recorded myself using it [here](http://shelr.tv/records/53befbf2966080674200010f) so you can watch a terminal session of how it works.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for taking the time to come up with this and explain it so well. I really appreciate it. However, it is so much beyond my skill level, that I really don't understand much, even with your profound explanations. when I run the script on a directory of test-files (script being in the same directory), it shows it is going to rename all files to the same filename, it does not show any incremented numbers. when I run the version without echo, all files are gone afterwards and the script itself gets renamed to `20140707_SHOOTNAME_`

Comment: @Seul? Why did you run it without echo? Oh, I see, with test files - sorry. It show that because for whatever reason your sh is not supportng `$LINENO`. Can you try doing `echo $LINENO`? I don't understand why it would no be supported - you have copied in the quotes exactly, right? They're important. And I can't speak for `bash` - so I wouldn't recommend using it - but `sh` should work with this. `$LINENO` is specified by POSIX. Also - don't put the script in the same directory - else change the `*` to `*.NEF` in both the first and last lines.

Comment: @Seul - if `$LINENO` doesn't work, this probably will - try changing the first line to - `stat --printf='}" "%z_${SN}_$((i=i+1)).NEF"\n' -- *.NEF |` ... and the last line to ... `SN=SHOOTNAME sh -s -- *.NEF`

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried with sh and that works better. However, three issues with your last piece of code (after "or maybe"):

Comment: a) the file extension gets lost

Comment: b) the date prefix is indeed wrong. I created the test-files yesterday, but copied them into a new test folder today. They get today's date, so I possibly misunderstood the explanation behind the link you sent yesterday and am not looking for ctime after all. Sorry for the confusion, but as I said, my skill level here is pretty low. I also tried @Gilles' solution and there the date is right (yesterday).

Comment: c) the sorting. I created four files: `_DSC12345.NEF-_DSC12348.NEF`. Then as last file a fifth `_DSC0000.NEF`. I also modified the last one after creating it. By »sorting by creation date« I hoped that `0000` becomes the file with the highest number after renaming. This is important because my camera's file naming jumps to 0000 after 9999, so potentially I can shoot 10 images with 9995-9999 being before 0000-0004. In your solution, file `0000` becomes `1` where it should be `5`.

Comment: @Seul - I know about the `date` - I suspected it as well. As I said in the answer though - you can use the various forms interchangeably with this: - you can try any one of `%w`-`%z` and find which you like best. They'll all work the same because the format is identical. The `0000` situation you describe is due to all files having the same date. I can fix that by making the times more specific - as is it chops the `NS` and etc fields from the output, and so they're *only* sorted by date - not minutes or seconds. That's very easily handled.

Comment: @Seul - and sorry about the file extension - I added it. I'm trying to think of the best way to do the other thing. Should only be a few minutes.