# rename mov/mts files with exif data

Tags: rename, exif

I am trying to rename mov/mts files with their exif data. I have checked various
ways with shotwell, gthumb, etc. Although gthumb does recognise the data, it will not rename (only jpg). I also looked at exiftool and pyrename/krename. 
If a command-line suggestion, please explain in a simple way as I do not fully understand command lines.

Comment: If you're only "renaming" them, using your file manager, then the exif data should still be there. You aren't changing the contents, only the name. Because some programs use the extension to guess that the file is, and where to look for meta data, they get it wrong, but it's still there. If you want to have the exif data in the right place, and format, for the new extension, then you don't want to rename them, you want to convert them. And that can be done with lots of tools. Maybe with VLC to avoid the command line? Or ffmpeg if you can take the time to learn it. Could be worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - I am hoping for a name that is the date & time the movie was created - as mentioned gthumb shows the date and time eg 18/8/05  09.43:32 but will not rename movie files -

Comment: Extracting the exif data, and using it to rename the files is a whole 'nother kettle of phisch :/ I'll wager that's going to require some command work, if not scripting even. And, with date/time having bad filename characters, it could be risky if not carefully implemented.

Comment: On Ubuntu forums a member seems to have written a bash script -       https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328946 but it would need explaining to me ...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mejpark/2293979

Comment: @don_crissti Give that one a gold star! With an, obviously short, explanation, that ought to be written up as _the_ answer.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver - it's been [already explained here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110581) - so this is pretty much a duplicate (the only difference is the file type/extension); the link in my previous comment was the 1st result of a quick google search as I had no time to search for duplicates here...